# QGIS information by clicking on a point?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, geotag

How is it possible to open a window by clicking on a point of a point shapefile? This window should display particular attributes of the attribute table and, if somehow possible, geotagged photos.

Is it possible and useful with photo2shape or eVIS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible even without any additional plugins.

You have to enable "auto open feature form" to open the form automatically when clicking with the "identify" map tool.

You have to configure the form and fields in the layer properties.

You can use the drag and drop designer on the fields page of the properties to only enable certain fields and group and order them.

You can use the photo widget to show pictures in the popup form.

There are some resources for it on [this blog](https://mapoholic.wordpress.com/2013/12/27/creating-custom-forms-in-qgis-part-1/) and a bit older in the [*Forms* chapter of the QGIS training manual](http://manual.linfiniti.com/en/create_vector_data/forms.html) for details.

Comment: thank you. didn't this is so straight forward. will have a look at it in the afternoon!

Comment: @Matthias Kuhn yes of course ;-) wanted to check it first and try it :D. It works perfectly fine!